# Multiline text in tableview row in Titanium

Tags: ios, uitableview, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm working on a tableView based application in Titanium.
I need to show long text contents in my table view rows.

When I do this, my row is looking like:

[image: Multiline]

This is the code I'm using to create my table view row.

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        backgroundColor : '#F0F0F0',
        color           : 'black',
        font            : { fontSize:10 ,fontWeight:'bold',fontFamily:'Arial'},
        height          :'80',
        title           : firstRowContent
     });
```

My issue is I need to wrap the text in my table view row and need to display it in multiline.

In iOS there is `lineBreakMode` and `numberOfLines` properties. And I can easily do it.

Is there any way to do it in titanium ? I searched a lot, but everyone says that put a '**\n**' in between the text or add multiple labels.

These are the links I referred:

1. [multiline label](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/54351/multiline-label)
2. [multiline text textwrap linebreaks in buttons and table view items](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/14151/multi-line-texttext-wrapline-breaks-in-buttons-and-table-view-items)
3. [Display resultset (text) within a label, multiline](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/59521/display-resultset-text-within-a-label-multiline)
4. [Multiline Label?](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/54351/multiline-label)
5. [mutiline tablerow from database](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122819/mutiline-tablerow-from-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding a label as subview of tableview's row.

```
 var firstRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        backgroundColor : '#F0F0F0',
        color           : '#555555',
        font            : { fontSize:10 ,fontFamily:'Arial'},
        height          :'auto',
       // title         : firstRowContent,
        horizontalWrap  : 'true',
        selectionStyle  : Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE
     });
      var firstLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text            : 'Midhun Says: Hi, How are you ? We are currently waiting for you ...',
        height          : 'auto',
        right           : '10',
        top             : '7',
        left            : '10',
        color           : '#555555',
        font            : { fontSize:15 ,fontFamily:'Arial'},
     });

firstRow.add(firstLabel);
```

Anyway thanks guys for your help...

Answer (score 4):

You need to put a label object in the row. The label can be created such that it will wrap the text.

When searching for answers, search for complex tableviewrow appcelerator

Comment: I had already fixed this issue by adding a label. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The below wraps for me. Titanium's default label behavior is for it to wrap. A row view's "title" property is meant to be single lined.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
row.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Gosh golly, this is a label. Cool, huh?',
    color: '#000', font: { fontSize: 32 }
}));
win.add(Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: [ row ]
}));
win.open();
```

If you were to set a height on the row such that a wrapped line wouldn't fit, then it will ellipsize for you.

```
row.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: 'Gosh golly, this is a label. Cool, huh?',
    color: '#000', font: { fontSize: 32 },
    height: 40
}));
```

But it'll by default size to the content you've provided.

Comment: I had already fixed this issue by adding a label. Thanks for your answer.